# Python sorting issue x[y[:,0]>50]

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone please explain what this line in python returns?
I know its probably easy but completely new to python here.

```
    result = x[y[:,0]>50]
```

result, x, y are all arrays.

Comment: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple" is produced.

Comment: Is that pure `Python` or, I guess, with something like `numpy`?

Comment: @RamchandraApte Syntax like that is totally fine with `numpy`, while `y[:,0]` is actually `[i[0] for i in y]`

Comment: @starrify what`s up with so many newby questions about python, that at the same time uses numpy?

Comment: @nette If you are talking about NumPy arrays then please edit the question and add the [tag:numpy] tag.

Comment: Try it out in an interactive environment like `IPython`. This is a great way to learn Python and get immediate feedback on your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your "arrays" are `numpy.ndarray`s,

Break it apart into pieces:

```
y[:,0]
```

This returns an array *view*.  You can think of it as a new array (for now).  There are significant differences, but they don't come into play here.  This is a view of the first column of your original array.  e.g.:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> a[:,0]
array([0, 3, 6])
```

Now, the next part:  `y[:,0] > number`.  This returns a new *boolean* array.  The condition is evaluated for each element in the array (or view) on the left and put in the output.

```
>>> a[:,0] > 4
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Finally, we have a boolean indexing operation.  This takes elements from the outer array where the boolean inner array are `True`.

```
>>> arr2
array([ 8, 42, 63])
>>> a[:,0] > 4  # Just a reminder ...
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> arr2[a[:,0] > 4]
array([63])
```

Comment: "This is a view of the first row of your original array" - first column.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Yes, that's what I meant.  I even went over that in my head before I posted ... I suppose it's hard to get the fortran out of my system.  :)

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful, now I have to do the same thing in Java, any ideas?

Comment: @nette -- Java?  Where did that come from?  I have no idea.  I don't know any Java ... But good luck.

Comment: Converting opencv python code to opencv android code. The opencv part is fine but the python numpy operations are becoming a bit painful.